# Why doesn't maven include the JSP files in my jar?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, web-applications, jetty

I have an embedded jetty (version 8.1.8) web app I am packaging as a jar and which uses JSP for its frontend. It is built with maven version 3.0.3. The problem is that when I do: `mvn package` it is including everything except my *.jsp files. I've tried to relocate them many different places but no luck.

I've tried to add `<include>src/main/java/**/*.jsp</include>` to the `maven-compiler-plugin` section of my pom. But that had no effect either.

Is there a way to be certain that jsp files get included?

Comment: Do you use `maven jar plugin` or `maven war plugin` to create the jar file?

Comment: I'm using `maven-jar-plugin`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My solution was to add the jsp files to src/main/webapp and to add the following snippet in the pom file:

```
<build>
    <resources>
      ...
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Comment: I found that this wipes out the regular resource inclusion unless you do a second `<resource>` block for that too.

Comment: @end-user the `...` after the `resource` block was to indicate that this was simply an additional resource, not replacing any existing resources. However, I've added another set of ellipses preceding the  resource block that hopefully makes that more clear.

Comment: No, I understand the meaning of an ellipsis is to indicate other elements may be present.  What I'm suggesting is (I believe) the default behavior of Maven, without specifying a `<resources>` block, is to include whatever's in `src/main/resources`.  However if you direct it to `webapp`, it overrides the default, requiring you specify both (if you need both).

Answer (score 4):

Try to place .jsp into src/main/resources, Maven ignores all but .java files in src/main/java

Comment: hmmm, just tried. Doesn't appear that the src/main/resources directory is being added to the jar either. I'm checking contents using the jar command

Comment: Use `$ mvn clean package` to create the jar file, then test its contents.  One of your configured plugins is causing the problems you are seeing.  Start with no `<plugins>`, then add each plugin back until it breaks again.  Then fix that specific plugin's configuration.

Comment: so in order to get the src/main/resources folder to show up in my jar I actually had to add that folder to the pom like so: 

`<build><resources><resource>src/main/resources</resource></resources>...</build>`

Comment: src/main/resources is default. it's not the directory itself but its content that gets to jar. if you place 1.jsp in src/main/resources you'll get 1.jsp in jar root